# Obj Var or With Block Var Not Set

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I must be wearing out all of my questions in 2 days.  But here is one more.

I have some code that someone helped me with and I am getting an Object Variable error.

```
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim c As Range
Dim rngToDelete As Range

With Worksheets(5).Range("c1:c1500")
   Set c = .Find("-", LookIn:=xlValues)
   If Not c Is Nothing Then
       firstAddress = c.Address
       Do
           If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
              Set rngToDelete = c
           Else
              Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, c)
           End If
           Set c = .FindNext(c)
           If c Is Nothing Then Exit Do
       Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
   End If
End With

If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
```

It is blocking out at the last rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete

Not sure why, can only think it might have something to do with the fact that no "-" were found.

Help please.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to delete here but once you cannot find "-" (i.e. c IS nothing), rngToDelete is not defined and thus the error occurs.

Comment: That is what I figured, do you have any suggestions on how to correct it if no - are found?

Comment: If you are meant to delete every row you found with "-", I think Gary's student have the answer~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reverse the logic:

```
If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
```